# How do I access an object in a different module in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have two modules:

```
angular.module('test1', [])
    .run(function() {
        var numbers = [1, 2, 3,4];
        // do more operations on numbers here
    });

angular.module('test2', [])
    .run(function() {
        // I want to edit or iterate over numbers here
    });
```

I want to be able to edit the variable `numbers` in the `test2` module. I'm extremely new to Angular so it seems like the easiest way to do this is to put numbers in $rootscope but that doesn't seem too desirable.

What's the most idiomatic way to achieve this? Do I make numbers a `.value()`? Do I make it into a service? Do I make 'editor' depend on 'test' (a concept that I am still trying to grasp)?

Comment: can you provide more clarification about your problem? do you want to write an editor?

Comment: That's pretty much the problem. I have a var in one module that I want to acess in another module. I named the module `editor` because it was going to edit the `numbers` variable. I'll change it for less confusion.

Comment: it can be done by services, read my anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a service to pass data. Here is an example how you can try it.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['access','test1','test2']);
angular.module('access', [])
    .service('accessService', function() {
        this.numbers = [1, 2, 3,4];
        // do more operations on numbers here
    });

angular.module('test1', [])
    .run(function(accessService) {
        var numbers = accessService.number;
        // do more operations on numbers here
    });

angular.module('test2', [])
    .run(function(accessService) {
       accessService.numbers.forEach(function(number){
         console.log(number)
       })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jorawar. Would setting `numbers` as a value of the `test1` module and then just setting `test1` as a dependency of `test2` also work?

The reason I ask this is because in this example (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), the `xmpl.service` module seems to do it with the `greeter` value.

Comment: you are wellcome!! you can accept my answer if you achieved your goal with my answer :-)

Comment: I just edited my earlier comment, could you take a look?

Comment: like this may be if i followed you right? :-)      
   var app = angular.module('app', ['test1','test2']);
  angular.module('test1', []).value('numbers', [1,2,3,4]);

 angular.module('test2', ['test1'])
 .run(function(numbers) {
 console.log(numbers)
        // I want to edit or iterate over numbers here
    });

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that! Which one would be better/more suited towards angular?

Comment: It'd depend on your need. Value give you not so many options but service give you more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118277/discussion-between-jorawar-singh-and-joshualan).

Answer (score 1):

I think that run blocks are not the place to store data, it is usually a place to do app initialization I guess.

If you have a list of numbers that you want to be used and modified by others, you can use a service that have those numbers as its property and inject that service anywhere you like, and since services are singleton everyone who accesses that service is working with one and only one object.

you can also think an directives, I have `numbers` in some scope, I create an `editor` directive that uses `two-way` data-binding to access and modify that property on the scope.

Hope it helps